# Inversion with two clauses?

Tags: subject-verb-inversion

```
a) Only after I had explained everything, did he stop blaming and did she stop crying.
b) Only after I had explained everything, did he stop blaming and she stop crying.
c) Only after I had explained everything, did he stop blaming and she stopped crying.
d) Only after I had explained everything, did he stop blaming and was she satisfied.
e) Only after I had explained everything, did he stop blaming and she was satisfied.
```

Which ones are correct in grammar?

Comment: Seems you could narrow your choice since only two sentences contain two inversions. You also don't need a comma after the first clause; it's not natural to pause there.

Comment: c and e are ungrammatical, and I'd say d sounds outlandish.